# Is it true that we can replace all classes that implement multiple interfaces?

Tags: java, oop, interface, language-agnostic

I think we can always replace class with multiple interfaces e.g.:

```
public class C implements A,B{
}
```

into another version that each class contains at most one interface ,is it true (I just want to ask "If we can...", not "If we should..." here)?

Consider C which overrides methods a() from A, and b() B:

```
public class C implements A,B{
    @override
    public void a(){
    }

    @override
    public void b(){
    }
}
```

it is volating single responsibility principle because either change a() or b() requires change C, instead we can wrap A and B with an independent class:

```
public class ConcreteA implements A{
    @override
    public void a(){
    }
}

public class ConcreteB implement B{
    @override
    public void b(){
    }
}

public class C{
    ConcreteA a;
    ConcreteB b;
}
```

is it true?

And even your class has a single responsibility which requires 2 interface, it is still possible to rewrite it to become one interface only in each class,e.g.,the original version:

```
public class C implements A,B{
    @Override
    public void a(){
    }

    @Override
    public void b(){
        a();
    }
}
```

in this case we can rewrite it as:

```
public class ConcreteA implements A{
    @Override
    public void a(){
    }
}

public class C implements B{
    ConcreteA a;
    @Override
    public void b(){
        a.a();
    }
}
```

So my question is, is it true that we can replace all of our classes that contain more than 2 interfaces into the version that contains at most one interface only?

if not, at what situations I need to implement more than one interface to finish the task?

Comment: No, it is not true. What if one of the interfaces is `Serializable`?

Comment: By the way, based on your examples, you mean "at least 2" (`>= 2`), not " more than 2" (`> 2`).

Comment: Did you mean `public class C extends ConcreteA implements B` or that when B is defined it also implements A in the definition? so that both the methods a() and b() are accessible on instances of the C class?

Comment: In theory you could split up many of such classes but in practice there's often a need to implement multiple interfaces, e.g. when you need to implement `Cloneable` as well as `Serializable` on some data class. Or consider a case where `a()` and `b()` would have to operate on the same instance data. You probably could move that data to a third class or into either `ConcreteA` or `ConcreteB` but that wouldn't reduce coupling which is the goal of srp.

Answer (score 0):

The question whether implementing multiple interfaces or using multiple inheritance in general violates the single responsibility principle has been discussed before, for example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11855335/does-implementing-multiple-interface-violate-single-responsibility-principle). There seems to be no clear consensus about it. To my opinion, the definition of SRP you are using is too strict.

The `Serializable` interface mentioned in the comments is a special case because it is a marker interface that does not declare any methods. But there are other interfaces like `Runnable` that usually make no sense to be used alone.

Coming back to your question: Yes, in theory it is possible but not without breaking other important principles like DRY (don't repeat yourself). Just think of a class that not only implements methods declared in the implemented interfaces but also its own method:

```
public class C implements A,B {
    public void a(){}
    public void b(){}
    public void c(){}
}
```

Splitting results in:

```
public class CA implements A {
    public void a(){}
    public void c(){}
}

public class CB implements B {
    public void b(){}
    public void c(){}
}
```

Now method `c()`is duplicated. Yes, you could use an additional interface `C` or put this method into some kind of utility class, but I'd say that this will typically not improve the design.